# Get feature importance for the model trained using RandomizedSearchCV and Multinomial Naiye Bayes

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, naivebayes

After fitting the model, can not get the feature importance. I have done following steps:

`model_bow = RandomizedSearchCV(MultinomialNB(class_prior=[0.5,0.5]),param_distributions={'alpha':alpha},scoring='roc_auc',n_iter=10,return_train_score=True,)`

`model_bow.fit(X_train_en_bow,y_train)`

`model_bow.best_params_` gives me `best value is {'alpha': 0.5}`

now if i want the feature importance using `model_bow.estimator.feature_log_prob_`, it gives an error as below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-cc27acc11117> in <module>
----> 1 model_bow.estimator.feature_log_prob_()

AttributeError: 'MultinomialNB' object has no attribute 'feature_log_prob_'
```

when i print model_bow it shows

```
                   param_distributions={'alpha': [1e-05, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01,
                                                  0.1, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 50,
                                                  100]},
                   return_train_score=True, scoring='roc_auc')
```

Please advice where i am missing !

Comment: `feature_log_prob_` is a property, not a method. Try removing the `()` when you use it.

Comment: There is NO ( ) already.

Comment: It's in the traceback. Can you add the actual code where you access it the property?

Answer (score -1):

To get feature importance, get the best model trained using

`model_bow.best_params_`

then you can call the method `coef_` (will get depreciated soon) or `feature_log_prob_` to get feature importance.